# Difference between rpart and tree in R

Tags: r

I thougt `rpart` and `tree` are exactly the same until I ran into this problem.

I have a data frame `wikiWords` with 329 columns. 328 of them are predicting varibales and they are all `num`. The left one is `Vandal` - the response and is a `factor`. `str(wikiWords)` is:

```
'data.frame':   3876 obs. of  329 variables:
 $ A accord                      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ A actual                      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ A ago                         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ A agre                        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ A analog                      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ A appar                       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ A arbitrari                   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ A believ                      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ A biolog                      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ A biologyanalog               : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ A bodi                        : num  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ A call                        : num  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 ......
 $ Vandal                        : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

This works fine:

```
wikitree = rpart(Vandal ~ .,data=wikiWords,method = 'class')
```

But this shows an error:

```
wikitree = tree(Vandal ~ .,data=wikiWords,method = 'class')
```

The error is: "Error in `[.data.frame`(frame, predictors) : undefined columns selected"

I really dont know what is wrong. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you provide `str(wikiWords)`? I tried the code with simulated data and everything is fine, so I guess that maybe there's an issue with non standard column names? But without an idea of your data that'S a pure guess.

Comment: @thothal: Added already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is due to the problem with your column names, which has space in it. causing this error

this is working fine:

```
set.seed(1000)
tmp <- data.frame(sample(0:1,100,replace=T, prob=c(0.5,.5)),V1=rnorm(100),V2=rnorm(100))
colnames(tmp) <- as.character(c('Target','aword','bword'))


library(rpart)
rpart(Target~.,data=tmp)

library(tree)
tree(Target~.,data=tmp)
```

this is not working since column names has space in it

```
set.seed(1000)
tmp <- data.frame(sample(0:1,100,replace=T, prob=c(0.5, 0.5)),V1=rnorm(100),V2=rnorm(100))
colnames(tmp) <- as.character(c('Target','a word','b word'))

library(rpart)
rpart(Target~.,data=tmp)

library(tree)
tree(Target~.,data=tmp)
```

Comment: But in your second example, `rpart` still works. Do you know the reason why?

Comment: rpart implementation has a flexibility in using features names have space in it. where as tree has no such flexibility